# Factorials and finding the even factorial of them

Tags: c#, declaration, factorial

I'm trying to get my factorial program to work which takes a number from the user and calculates its even factorial. i.e 6! is 720 and its even factorial is 6x4x2 = 48 except I've figured out how to do the factorial part but whenever I try to add more code so I can try calculate the rest I get "Operator `%` cannot be applied to operands of type `method group` and `int`" or "Unexpected symbol `{` in class, struct, or interface member declaration" and I cant seem to see what I'm doing wrong. Any advice would be helpful

```
using System;
namespace Factorial
{
    class Factorial
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter a number");
            int i =int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            long fact = GetFactnum(i);
            Console.WriteLine("{0} factorial is {1}", i, fact);           
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        public static long GetFactnum(int i)
        {          
            if (i == 0)
            {
                return 1;
            }
            return i * GetFactnum(i-1);
        }

     // public static void EvenFact()
     // {
     //     int sumofnums =0;   
     //     if((GetFactnum % 2) ==0)
     //         sumofnums += GetFactnum;
     // }
    }
}
```

Comment: Take a moment to read through the [editing help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) in the help center. Formatting on Stack Overflow is different than other sites. The better your post looks, the easier it will be for users to help you.

Comment: 1- `EvenFact` should take input parameter. 2- `if((GetFactnum % 2) ==0)` is wrong. See your previous function how a method call is done 3- `GetFactnum` is a good example for what yor are trying to do. 4- **Read some c# docs**

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Edit**

You had the basic idea but two things were incorrect.

First your `GetFactnum % 2` part is incorrect syntax. You need to have the form `int % int` and you basically gave it a `method group % int`. Which is why you got the error message. So you have to use the result (or return value) of `GetFactun(int i)` instead of the method name itself, like so:

```
int result = GetFactnum(i);
if((result % 2) == 0)
```

or you could use the return value immediately:

```
if((GetFactnum(i) % 2) == 0)
```

Secondly, I think you want to first check if the value is even or odd. What happens if you pass in an odd value of `i` does it still compute the even factorial? Or does it throw an error?

The way i would code the method is very similar to what you did for `GetFactnum(int i)`. But this time you check the input to see it it is odd or not. And secondly, if it is even, then you know that an even number minus 2 will equal another even number.

```
public static long GetEvenFactorial(int i) {
    if((i % 2) != 0) 
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("Input must be even!");
    }

    if (i <= 0)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    return i * GetEvenFactorial(i - 2);
}
```

Comment: You don't help OP by giving *fish*.

Comment: What EZI is saying is akin to the old adage, "Give a man a fish, he eats for a day.  Teach a man to fish and he feeds himself for a lifetime."

Comment: @ezi What do you mean? last time I check SO.com isn't a educational website. It is a question and answer website.

Comment: He is just trying to do his homework.  http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/give_a_man_a_fish_and_you_feed_him_for_a_day;_teach_a_man_to_fish_and_you_feed_him_for_a_lifetime

Comment: I know the stupid saying, I am arguing that it isn't applicable on StackOverflow.com unless they ask to be taught.

Comment: Thanks Moop! Don't worry EZI i'm learning and trying to understand from the mistakes I made and not just getting other people to do all the work

Comment: Guys, don't down-vote a good correct answer, even if it is a fish, not cool.

Comment: @alan2here I don't know if you have enough rep to read the initial version of the answer but just click on *"edited .... ago"* link

Comment: @Ezi if you think the question is homework-related, downvote the question, not answer. I did nothing wrong and it gives the impression that the answer is not correct.

Comment: @Moop I already said, "it should work". Homework questions can be asked here. But we generally avoid to post the working code, and try to explain the answer. What is so hard to understand? (BTW: this version of your answer is better, but I'll keep my downvote)

Answer (score 0):

This is one way of finding the factorial of odd numbers:

```
int number = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
Console.WriteLine("Vlera e variables m: {0} \n", number);
  
long factorial = 1;
int i = 1;
Console.WriteLine(" x             f");
Console.WriteLine("---------------------------------");
while (i <= number)
{
    factorial *= i;
    if (i % 2 != 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(" {0}             {1}", i, factorial);
    }
    i++;
}
Console.WriteLine("----------------------------------");
```